# I want to fetch all the items in the categories field using a vue component

Tags: vue.js

I have the following vue component CreateProduct.vue

```
<template>
   <div>
        <div class="row mb-4">
            <label for="category" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-end">Category</label>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <select class="form-select col-md-6">
                    <option value="">Select category</option>
                    <option v-for="item in categories" :key="item.id" :value="item.id">{{item.category}}</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>   

        <div class="row mb-4">
            <label for="subcategory" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-end">Subcategory</label>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <select name="subcategory_id" id="subcategories" class="form-select col-md-6">
                    <option value="">Select subcategory</option>
                    <option value="">Subcategory A</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        data(){
            return{
                categories : {},
                subcategories : {}
            }
        },

        mounted() {
            axios.get('/api/categories')
            .then(response => {
                this.categories = response.data;
            });
        },
    }
</script>
```

The component is supposed to fetch all the categories. However, I am not getting any category on the browser. Just blank. What could be the issue>

Comment: Looks like categories should be an `array` instead of `object`. Also cross check that you are getting data properly in `response.data`. I am just adding a working code snippet below. Please check and try to find the root cause of the issue you are facing

Comment: Yeah, I tested for the response. And that's what I was getting. I just dont know why the same is not being rendered on the front end

Comment: You can have a look on below answer and can tell me what is the change so that it will be easy to find the root cause

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine, I am just creating a code snippet below, You can check and try to find out the root cause.

Just for the demo I am mocking the response. But you can use the response getting from axios call.

Demo **:**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    categories : [],
    subcategories : []
  },
  mounted() {
    // Just for the demo I am mocking the response. But you can cross check if this is the same type you are getting from axios call.
    const responseData = [{
      id: 1,
      category: 'Category 1'
    }, {
      id: 2,
      category: 'Category 2'
    }, {
      id: 3,
      category: 'Category 3'
    }, {
      id: 4,
      category: 'Category 4'
    }];
    this.categories = responseData 
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div class="row mb-4">
            <label for="category" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-end">Category</label>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <select class="form-select col-md-6">
                    <option value="">Select category</option>
                    <option v-for="item in categories" :key="item.id" :value="item.id">{{ item.category }}</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>   

        <div class="row mb-4">
            <label for="subcategory" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-end">Subcategory</label>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <select name="subcategory_id" id="subcategories" class="form-select col-md-6">
                    <option value="">Select subcategory</option>
                    <option value="">Subcategory A</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```